# Mono for Android - All activities in Portrait orientation

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have a MonoDroid application and I'd like to force all my Activities to be presented only in Portrait orientation.

I'd though about creating a an Activity base classe such as:

```
[Activity (ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]         
public abstract class BaseActivity : Activity
{
}
```

All other activities in my application should then inherit from it (too avoid repetition and have a central place for defining the `ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait`).

However, if you look at the `ActivityAttribute` definition, looks like it does not support inheritance.

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class ActivityAttribute : Attribute { ... }
```

1. Do I have to put the `Activity (ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)` in ALL Activities of my application ?
2. Is it a bad idea to support only Portrait orientation in the Android world ? (I have a Portrait-only iOS application that works really well and does not need to operate on landscape).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the attribute on each Activity. If you were creating a native Android application you would need to mark each Activity in the manifest with `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`, using this attribute signals to Mono For Android to do the same.

Unfortunately the Attribute does not inherit as you noticed.

Comment: This really sux, because If I want to set some default themes / background images / orientation settings for my activities I can't make it in a base class. This lead to a lot of code repetition

Comment: @EduardoCoelho You can still use a base class, but each Activity needs to have the Orientation set individually